# When I click in scroll of modal windows, this windows pursues the cursor (only IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I need help, When I click in scroll of modal windows, this windows pursues the cursor (only IE)
As I can disable this? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is similar to this example

`http://jsfiddle.net/24A9b/7783/`

but this without scroll

```
enter code here
```